# How to set specific Hadoop version for Spark, Python

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I need help with setting a specific hadoop version in my spark config. I read somewhere that you can use the hadoop.version property. It doesn't say where to find it.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#specifying-the-hadoop-version

I need to set it from current/default to 2.8.0. Im coding in PyCharm. Please help, preferebly with a step-by-step guide.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do _"setting a specific hadoop version in my spark config"_? What is this for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build like that, for Apache Hadoop 2.7.X **and later**, so the above answer is correct.
[

```
 ./build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.7 -Dhadoop.version=2.7.0 -DskipTests clean package
```

]

Or you could modify this in the pom.xml of your spark downloaded distribution before performing the maven build, so that the building gets done with the version you want.

```
<profile>
    <id>hadoop2.8</id>
    <properties>
        <hadoop.version>2.8</hadoop.version>
    ...
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Take a look at [this post](https://etushar89.wordpress.com/2014/12/28/building-apache-spark-against-specific-hadoop-version/) for a step-by-step guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it while compiling. Please refer [building spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#specifying-the-hadoop-version).

To build with Hadoop 2.8 run

```
./build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.7 -Dhadoop.version=2.7.0 -DskipTests clean package
```

version 2.7 is for Hadoop 2.7.X and later

Comment: Shouldn't `hadoop.version` be `2.8.0` then?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski according to spark documentation, 2.7 is for Hadoop 2.7.X and later

Comment: What's `hadoop.version=2.7.0` for then? The OP asked about Hadoop 2.8.0, didn't he?

Comment: please refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#specifying-the-hadoop-version 
profile 2.7 is for 2.7 and later

Comment: Thanks @shekar, but how do I do this in PyCharm? This "while compiling method"